# Dynamically create objects in loop

Tags: c++, client-server

I come from Java so this is pretty hard for me to understand.. I am writing a client/server program to start learning C++.

```
ServerSocket server(30000);
while (true) {
    ServerSocket new_sock;
    server.accept(new_sock);

    std::cout << "client connected...\n";

    ClientConnectionThread *cct = new ClientConnectionThread(new_sock);
    cct->start();
}
```

My problem occurs when I try to write to the socket in the ClientConnectionThread.

```
client_sock << someObj;

Exception was caught in cct: Could not write to socket.
```

My assumption is that after the cc->start(); command the ServerSocket will lose 'scope' and be popped off the stack and automatically closed. To fix this I changed the code to:

```
ServerSocket server(30000);
while (true) {
    ServerSocket *new_sock; <----
    server.accept(new_sock);

    std::cout << "client connected...\n";

    ClientConnectionThread *cct = new ClientConnectionThread(new_sock);
    cct->start();
}
```

But the program didn't even enter the loop.. with no error messages telling me why that didn't work (Of course changing the necessary code to accept the pointer).

If it is not obvious what I am trying to do.. I am looking to create a new thread on every client connection to handle each client. Of course the thread will need a reference to the socket to receive and send on - which is why I pass it to the CCT object.

If you need more code let me know.

Comment: I don't see where you actually *create* *new_sock. Also, take care to balance `new` with `delete`.

Comment: Yeah - create the socket with new.  You can delete it when you eventually close it in the ClientConnectionThread.

Comment: Every `new` needs a `delete` otherwise it gets lonely.

Comment: Thanks all for the info!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first code does not work exactly because of what you said. The object is allocated on the stack but once it leaves of scope, it is destroyed and the underlying pointer to the socket is closed as a consequence.

If you want to keep the object "alive", you need to use pointers. You got that right, but missed a important point: you the to **allocate** the object! To do so, you need to use the operator `new` as the following:

```
ServerSocket *new_sock = new ServerSocket;
```

Now here's the catch, on Java your object gets deallocated automatically by GC, but C++ has no garbage collector, so you need to do it by hand. Once you are done using the object, you need to `delete` it.

```
delete new_sock;
```

This can be a lot tricky, can cause a lot of crashes and even memory leaks. If you wish some behaviour more like Java's GC, you can use a `shared_ptr`, that will automatically deallocate the object (it's not that simple, but you will easily find more about that on Google.)

```
std::shared_ptr<ServerSocket> new_sock = std::shared_ptr<ServerSocket>(new ServerSocket);
server.accept(*new_sock);
```

(assuming you are compiling against C++11)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, got it working. How does the shared_ptr know when to automatically deallocate the object? When the references to it = 0?

Comment: Meh - just delete it at the end of the client<> server thread. An outer-level catch should ensure that exceptions don't leave the thread without destroying the socket first.

Comment: Yes. Generally it creates several shared_ptr, every new instance adds 1 to the counter, once a shared_ptr is destroyed it decreases 1 from the count. When the count gets to 0, the last shared_ptr deletes the object. Also, note that the shared_ptr is not a real pointer, it just emulates one, the shared_ptr itself is statically allocated.

Answer (score 1):

You could make your first version work if you pass a copy instead of a reference of the ServerSocket to your thread (if that is possible - server socket would need a proper copy constructor for this). The original ServerSocket would go out of scope as you pointed out, which is now no longer a problem, as the copy is still valid.

If this is not an option for you go with the version Rogiel pointed out (and stick to resource handles like unique and shared pointer, those make your life a lot easier if you are used to GC :-) ).